# Windows inappbrowser cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, inappbrowser, webcam.js

We are building an windows 10 app for tablets using the webcam.js plugin. My camera works well in MS Edge browser, But How can I make it working as app on store using inappbrowser.

Also Can anyone tell me that, how can I set my browser as MS edge by default for app

Can anyone please assist me.

Robin Mandangada

Answer (score 1):

> My camera works well in MS Edge browser, But How can I make it working as app on store using inappbrowser.

The InAppBrowser window behaves like a standard web browser, and can't access Cordova APIs.

I think what you want is a hosted web app using Apache Cordova. You can create a Hosted Web App by following this document: [Create a hosted web app using Apache Cordova](http://taco.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/create-a-hosted-app/).